# Существует ли рабочий метод получение данных из Росреестра по кадастровому номеру?

Tags: api, rest, росреестр

Есть множество платных сервисов, есть такой официальный метод: http://rosreestr.gov.ru/api/online/fir_object/47:14:0901004:1818, но он работает не со всеми номерами, например http://rosreestr.gov.ru/api/online/fir_object/2:56:30302:639 — так работает, http://rosreestr.gov.ru/api/online/fir_object/47:14:0901004:1818 — вот так уже нет.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, здесь всё просто. Если после ":" сразу идут 0, то их нужно убирать в запросе, тогда всё будет работать. Например, последний не работающий запрос будет выглядить вот так:

```
http://rosreestr.gov.ru/api/online/fir_object/47:14:901004:1818.
```

Comment: Этот сайт не форум, или вы отвечаете, или [задаёте вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Удалил всё, что не относится к ответу, найдёте в [истории правок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1262902/revisions).

Answer (score 1):

Рабочего метода получения данных именно через api - нет, т.к. это api не работает.
Учитывая, что в [описании](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20REST-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%20rosreestr.gov.ru) есть пара существенных ошибок, а на самом сайте Росреестра этот документ поиском я не нашёл, степень доверия к результатам, полученным через это "api", изначально крайне невысока.

Руками https://rosreestr.gov.ru/wps/portal/online_request по адресу *обл Волгоградская, г Волжский, пр-кт им Ленина, д 142, кв 85* находится один объект с КН 34:35:030119:13320
Через api мне не удаётся найти его вообще никак:
ни по номеру
http://rosreestr.gov.ru/api/online/fir_objects/34:35:30119:13320
ни по id
http://rosreestr.gov.ru/api/online/fir_object/34:35:30119:13320
ни по адресу
[http://rosreestr.gov.ru/api/online/address/fir_objects?macroRegionId=118000000000&regionId=118410000000&street=ленина&house=142](http://rosreestr.gov.ru/api/online/address/fir_objects?macroRegionId=118000000000&regionId=118410000000&street=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&house=142)
и даже так ничего нет
http://rosreestr.gov.ru/api/online/address/fir_objects?macroRegionId=118000000000&house=142&apartment=85

Рабочий метод - берём питон + селениум, идём на https://rosreestr.gov.ru/wps/portal/online_request, щелкаем по кнопкам, парсим результат. Или реквестс. Или ПХП. Капчу на днях убрали, а всё остальное - проще простого.

Comment: добавили ключ доступа

Answer (score 0):

Основные API Публичной кадастровой карты (содержит почти такие же сведения, что и ФИР):

Получить заголовки объекта
[https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/api/typeahead/[TYPE]?text=[KADASTRAL_NUMBER]](https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/api/typeahead/%5BTYPE%5D?text=%5BKADASTRAL_NUMBER%5D)
Пример:
https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/api/typeahead/1?text=42:24:0101041:1117

Общие сведения об объекте
[https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/api/features/[TYPE]?text=[KADASTRAL_NUMBER]](https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/api/features/%5BTYPE%5D?text=%5BKADASTRAL_NUMBER%5D)
Пример:
https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/api/features/2?text=74:19:0701005:501

Расширенные сведения об объекте
[https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/api/features/[TYPE]/[ID_OBJECT]](https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/api/features/%5BTYPE%5D/%5BID_OBJECT%5D)
Пример:
https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/api/features/1/42:24:101041:1117

Переменные:

[TYPE] - следует заменить на код объекта (см. справочник ниже)

[KADASTRAL_NUMBER] - следует заменить на реестровый номер объекта

[ID_OBJECT] - тоже самое, что [KADASTRAL_NUMBER], но без ведущих нулей (вместо 42:04:0101041:1117 необходимо указать 42:4:101041:1117)

Cписок атрибутов:

```
id (String)                 : Идентификатор
cn (String)                 : Кадастровый номер
statecd (String)            : Статус
address (String)            : Адрес
kladr (String)              : Код КЛАДР
fp (String)                 : Форма собственности
adate (String)              : Дата выгрузки сведений из ГКН
anno_text (String)          : Надпись на карте
area_type (String)          : Тип площади
area_unit (String)          : Единицы измерения площади
area_value (String)         : Декларированная площадь
cad_cost (String)           : Кадастровая стоимость
cad_eng_data (String)       : Кадастровый инженер
cad_record_date (String)    : Дата изменения сведений в ГКН
cad_unit (String)           : Единицы измерения стоимости
category_type (String)      : Категория земель
date_cost (String)          : Дата внесения кадастровой стоимости
date_create (String)        : Дата постановки на учет
kvartal_cn (String)         : Кадастровый номер квартала
kvartal (String)            : Квартал
okrug_cn (String)           : Кадастровый номер округа
okrug (String)              : Округ
pubdate (String)            : Дата опубликования на ПКК
rayon_cn (String)           : Кадастровый номер района
rayon (String)              : Район
reg (String)                : Номер субъекта
rifr_cnt (String)           : Контактное лицо
rifr_dep (String)           : Орган власти
rifr (String)               : Свободен от прав третьих лиц
rights_reg (String)         : Зарегистрированы права (да/нет)
sale_cnt (String)           : Контактное лицо
sale_date (String)          : Дата проведения торгов
sale_dep (String)           : Орган власти
sale_price (String)         : Начальная цена
sale (String)               : Принято решение о проведении торгов
util_by_doc (String)        : Разрешенное использование по документу
util_code (String)          : Разрешенное использование
cc_date_approval (String)   : Дата утверждения категории земель
```

Список типов объектов:

```
LAND_LOT (number)                       : Земельные участки (1)
LAND_QUARTER (number)                   : Кварталы (2)
LAND_AREA (number)                      : Районы (3)
LAND_DISTRICT (number)                  : Округи (4)
CCO (number)                            : ОКСы (5)
TERRITORIAL_AREA (number)               : Территориальные зоны (6)
BOUNDARY (number)                       : Границы (7)
BOUNDARY_REFERENCE_NETWORK (number)     : ОМС (9)
USE_RESTRICTED_ZONE (number)            : ЗОУИТы (10)
FORESTRY (number)                       : Лесничества и лесопарки (12)
BUILDING_LINE (number)                  : Красные линии (13)
LAND_LOT_LAYOUT (number)                : Схемы расположения ЗУ (15)
FREE_ECONOMIC_ZONE (number)             : Свободные экономические зоны (16)
```

Что касается API http://rosreestr.gov.ru/api/online/fir_object/, то ФИР устаревший сервис доработка которого не осуществлялась с 2018го года, если память не изменяет, соответственно по каким-то объектам может работать некорректно или откровенно врать. Сервис официальный, но устаревший, увы.

Comment: ПКК (карта, которая) работает через похожий на ФИР сервис, но более свежий. Ошибки и не актуальная информация может быть, но это лучшее, что можно найти